# PHP array keys set as table headers dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

I have a bunch of serialized `$_POST`'s data stored into my database.After fetching and unserializing it, the data is represented as an array like below:

```
Array
(
    [size] => 1359sf
    [buyfor] => Investment
    [budget] => 401,000-500,000
    [fullname] => Chris Mark
    [age] => 36
    [semail] => mark.c@hotmail.com
    [phone] => 6781822333
)
```

Can these array keys be set into a `<th>` dynamically, like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>size</th>
      <th>buyfor</th>
      <th>budget</th>
      <th>fullname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  ..looping recordset..

</table>
```

Would this be possible?

**Edit**

Sorry my question is unclear, I want specific array keys only to be set into `<th>` due to some column are not necessary to be publish, let say

```
Array
(
    [size] => 1359sf
    [buyfor] => Investment
    [budget] => 401,000-500,000
    [fullname] => Chris Mark
    [age] => 36
    [semail] => mark.c@hotmail.com
    [phone] => 6781822333
)
```

I wanted to select only `size`, `buyfor` and `budget` to be set into `<th>`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      //fixed header
      <th>column 1</th>
      <th>column 2</th>

      //dynamic header
      <th>size</th>
      <th>buyfor</th>
      <th>budget</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  ..looping recordset..

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to build column headers of a table, which will represent the data from un-serialized array. If this is the case, then you can try looping trough array like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
<?php
  foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   echo "<th>".$key."</th>";
}

?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function to get keys

than

```
echo '<tr><th>';
echo implode('</th><th>', $keys);
echo '</th></tr>';
```